# How do I print a half-precision float using printf in the AMD OpenCL SDK?

Tags: printf, opencl

The Programming Guide has instructions for doubles (%ld) and vector types (e.g. %v4f), but not half-precision floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally in C, varargs arguments are [automatically promoted](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11c.html) to larger datatypes, such as float to double. The [OpenCL documentation](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/printfFunction.html) seems to imply that a similar promotion applies there.

Therefore a simple `%f` should work also for half-length floats.